# Установить vue-notify-me в laravel приложении

Tags: laravel, vue.js

Всем привет, 
В Laravel5.5/vue.js(2.5) приложении хочу использовать https://github.com/PygmySlowLoris/vue-notify-me либу:
Не понятно с ее использованием.
Я  установил библиотеку и создал файл resources/assets/js/components/lib/NotifyMe.vue с кодом из примера:

```
<notify-me
        container="notification"
        status="alert-success"
        :width="300"
        close="bootstrap"
        :event-bus="bus"
>
    <template slot="content" scope="{data}">
        <div style="width: 100%; word-break: break-all; text-align: left">
            <h4><b>{{data.title}}</b></h4>
            <p style="margin: 0">{{data.text}}</p>
        </div>
    </template>
</notify-me>
```

В resources/assets/js/app.js прописал:

```
import Notify from 'vue-notify-me'
```

В файле components/dashboard/DashboardIndex.vue  где я хочу использовать этот компонент :

```
<script>
    import {bus} from '../../app';
    import Notify from 'vue-notify-me';

    export default {
        data: function () {
            return {
                header_title : 'Dashboard',
                ...
            }

        },

        mixins : [appMixin],

        created() {
            this.app_bus = bus
        },

        mounted() {
            alert( " mounted notify-me   this.app_bus::"+(this.app_bus) )
            this.app_bus.$emit('notify-me', {
                data: {
                    title: 'The pygmy team :)',
                    text: 'this is my notification'
                }

            });
        }, // mounted() {
```

Сообщение не выскакивает И я не понял как подключить мой resources/assets/js/components/lib/NotifyMe.vue файл к этому компоненту?
Создавать и пользовать свои компоненты я умею...

Спасибо !

Comment: так ты тут Bas по новой что ли инициализировал ? чет тут ты не верно делаешь, там где app глобально объявляешь там же и bas объяви ну или на крайний случай засунь его в твой стартовый app и обращайся отовсюду к нему this.$root.bas.

Comment: Наверное решение с this.$root.bas будет лучше чем так как сделал я (это решение я нашел в обучалке)
Но в данный момент проблем а не в том : я не знаю как обращаться к созданному мною resources/assets/js/components/lib/NotifyMe.vue 
файлу и использовать код для сообшений ...

Comment: Ну заимпортил его, описал в components {'notify-me':NotifyMe} и затем где-то на странице его вызвал (в плане встаил тэг <notify-me :params>)